Evaluating $\int_0^{10} \operatorname{sn}(x\mid i) \, dx$
I am trying to evaluate:
$$\int_0^{10} \operatorname{sn}(x\mid i) \, dx$$
where $\operatorname{sn}$ denotes the Jacobi elliptic function sn.
The indefinite integral is:
$$(-1)^{3/4} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \operatorname{cd}(x\mid i)\right).$$
But I cannot substitute the limits to compute the definite integral because there is a discontinuity (of the indefinite integral) along the path around $x=7.07$. The definite integral can be computed if the point of discontinuity can be determined analytically.

the integrand does not have a singularity, it is continuous on $0<x<10$

the integrand is continuous, correct. I meant that the indefinite integral has a discontinuity.

crossposted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4980499/87355 --- it does not seem a trivial question, perhaps keep it open?

The indefinite integral
$$F(x)=(-1)^{3/4} \operatorname{arctanh}\left[(-1)^{1/4} \operatorname{cd}(x\mid i)\right]$$
of the Jacobi elliptic function $\operatorname{sn}(x\mid i)$ has a discontinuity of
$$\delta=2\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^{3/4} \operatorname{arctanh}\left[(-1)^{1/4} z\right]=
-\frac{(1+i) \pi }{\sqrt{2}}$$ at $x=7.0748\cdots$ [arising from the pole in $\operatorname{cd}(x\mid i)$], hence the definite integral equals
$$\int_0^{10} \operatorname{sn}(x\mid i) \, dx=F(10)-F(0)+\delta.$$
This evaluates to $-2.42813 - 2.31227\, i$, in agreement with a numerical evaluation of the integral.

Thanks @CarloBeenakkerr, very helpful indeed
